# Access get_root of a MPTT model through a query

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

Consider below example:

```
class ModelX(models.Model):
    fieldX = models.ForeignKey(ModelY)

class ModelY(MPTTModel):

    def root(self):
        return get_root()

    root = property(root)
```

Now I would like to make query like this

```
ModelX.objects.filter(fieldX__root=match)
```

or better yet directly calling `get_root()` like this

```
ModelX.objects.filter(fieldX__get_root=match)
```

which would make the `root()` method superfluous.

None of the above seem to work though. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.filter()` takes as keyword arguments [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups). From docs:

> *Changed in Django 1.4*: The field specified in a lookup has to be **the name of a model field**.
>   There's one exception though, in case of a ForeignKey you can specify
>   the field name suffixed with _id. In this case, the value parameter is
>   expected to contain the raw value of the foreign model's primary key.

This means you can not make queries based on model methods. There are some snippets that may help you:

```
#returns all ModelX objects related to root nodes
ModelX.objects.filter(fieldX__level=0)

#first: get descendants of root node with id=1 (it can be any field lookups)
#second: get all ModelX nodes, related to previously founded nodes
nodes = ModelY.object.get(level=0, id=1).get_descendants()
ModelX.objects.filter(fieldX__in=nodes)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I was looking for. I want to get all ModelX objects whose fieldX point to a foreignkey that has a certain root. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `fieldX` should point to a root node or to any descendant of a certain root node?

Comment: One more detail: is there only one certain root node or it can be multiple of them? It is important, because `mptt` has no built in method for `.get_descendants` for a list of nodes.

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean, but no, there should only be one associated root node with each object (that can be accessed via `get_root()`). And so my problem is that I want to get all objects that belong to a specific root node.